# jQuery table refresh but duplication occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to refresh content of my data table at each second. The following code works but it duplicates other objects as seen below picture.

[image]

Its code, `tableHolder` is table id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#{tableHolder}').DataTable();
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('.dataTakenFromTheUrl’, function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

I’ve tried the following also but don’t work. I get `DataTables warning: table id=tableHolder - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see datatables.net/tn/1`

```
var table = $('#tableHolder').DataTable();
table.ajax.reload();
```

I need something like in my first example. If I remove the following part, *show 10 entries, search bar, ordering arrows disappear.*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('#{tableHolder}').DataTable();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the version of the datatable. 
**If the datatable version is old then use :**

```
var table = $('#tableHolder').DataTable();
table.api().ajax.reload();
```

**If the version is New then use :**

```
var table = $('#tableHolder').DataTable();
table.ajax.reload();
```

I hope using the above script your problem will be resolved.

Comment: it doesn’t work means i get the following error _DataTables warning: table id=tableHolder - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1_

Comment: The problem I don’t get json from the _dataTakenFromTheUrl_. I get generated table HTML codes. New version 2.x